# Constructor error and variable resolution

Tags: java, android

My android application stops unexpectedly. I have looked into the affected class as directed by the logcat but don't seem to know where the error is coming from.

```
enter code here
03-23 14:22:11.258: D/AndroidRuntime(274): Shutting down VM
03-23 14:22:11.258: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  com cannot be resolved to a variable
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  example cannot be resolved to a variable
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  virtualgallery cannot be resolved to a variable
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  Main cannot be resolved to a variable
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.example.virtualgallery.VirtualGallery$SplashHandler.<init>(VirtualGallery.java:25)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.example.virtualgallery.VirtualGallery.onCreate(VirtualGallery.java:45)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-23 14:22:11.258: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 14:22:16.748: I/Process(274): Sending signal. PID: 274 SIG: 9
```

Here is the affected class

```
public class VirtualGallery extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            Handler x = new Handler();
            x.postDelayed(new SplashHandler(), 2000);   
    }

    class SplashHandler implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(VirtualGallery.this, Main.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

here's the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.example.virtualgallery" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="10"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  android:allowBackup="true">


        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".VirtualGallery">            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Main">
            <action android:name="com.example.virtualgallery.main" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Main2">
            <action android:name="com.example.virtualgallery.main" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Main3">
            <action android:name="com.example.virtualgallery.main" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Pic">
            <action android:name="com.example.virtualgallery.main" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You are mixing old classes with new classes. Delete all your *.class files, recompile all your source code, fix possible errors, re-install your app on your device.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that I am mixing up my codes? Because that's actually correct. I lost the initial application codes but de-compiled the .apk file, and copied over the classess and xml files to a new project. Evidently, i have messed things up,. Any suggestions as to how to compile the source code correctly. I am quite new to programming.

Comment: Try `(new SplashHandler().run();, 2000);`

Comment: @user3263215 Because the error says "Unresolved compilation problems" and says that several variables could not be found in your classes.

Comment: Is there a way to correctly compile my source code, as i am getting it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Handler x = new Handler();
  x.postDelayed(new SplashHandler(), 2000);



}

class SplashHandler implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}



}
```

make sure that you declare the Activity in Manifest

Comment: But thats's the same code i've got and i get the same error.

Comment: 1. Make sure that the Activity is proper declared in Manifest
2. Make sure that the setContentView(R.layout.splash); is inflating the right xml file.

If it is okay then
Run the program and save the whole Log and send it